# How to put some parameters to one gdx file

Tags: gams-math

I want to read some parameters from an excel file and put all of them in a gdx file. For putting a parameter in a gdx file I use the following code:

```
parameter a(i,k);

    $ call gdxxrw Parameters.xlsx par a rng=a!A1:C101 rdim=1 cdim=1
    $ gdxin Parameters.gdx
    $ load a
    $gdxin
```

But when I do this for other parameter, the gdx file keep only the last parameter while I want to add other parameters to the same gdx file(Parameters.gdx).

What shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

Did you do the `$call gdxxrw ...` mutliple times? Then you probably overwrote the previous GDX files by the last call. Just do it on one call like this:

```
parameter a(i,k), b(i,k);

$ call gdxxrw Parameters.xlsx par=a rng=a!A1:C101 rdim=1 cdim=1  par=b rng=b!A1:C101 rdim=1 cdim=1
$ gdxin Parameters.gdx
$ load a b
$gdxin
```

If this becomes too long/ugly have a look at the [index option](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/T_GDXXRW.html#GDXXRW_OPTIONS_INDEX) or store the options in a text file, which you can reference with the `@` sign, e.g. `$call gdxxrw Parameters.xlsx @howToRead.txt`.